# Calculate area between two multivalued curves

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I have to calculate the area between two curves which will give me the result of a particular quantity. However, both the curves are multivalued functions. Here is a data set showing the region where I have to calculate the area.
[image: Data set between whom the area is to be calculated]

The area to be calculated is the area between the red and the black curve in the range of x axis specified. However, I am unable to approximate a function for the curves and then to calculate the area.I tried to interpolate the two curves and then calculate the area but without any result. 
Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were is the data set?????

Answer (score 5):

This is a toy example that I hope will facilitate or motivate approach.

```
f[a_, x_] := a x^2/(1 + a x^2)
dat = Join[Table[{j, f[1, j]}, {j, 0, 6, 0.1}], 
   Table[{j, f[3, j]}, {j, 6, 0, -0.1}]];
{xs, ys} = Transpose[dat];
xf = ListInterpolation[xs, {0, 1}];
yf = ListInterpolation[ys, {0, 1}];
reg = Disk[{1, 0.4}, {1, 0.1}];
regp = Polygon[Table[{xf[j], yf[j]}, {j, 0, 1, 0.01}]];
int = RegionIntersection[reg, regp];
ri = RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion[reg],
   DiscretizeRegion[regp]];
rp = RegionPlot[ri];
Show[ParametricPlot[{xf[t], yf[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {Circle[{1, 0.4}, {1, 0.1}]}], rp, AspectRatio -> 1]
Area[ri]
```

[image]

Summary:

- interpolate and parametrize your curves
- convert into regions
- region intersection
- determine area of intersection

Visualization to help further refinement, e.g. `MaxCellMeasure` etc

Answer (score 3):

This is a pre-v10 way.

Let's start by proposing a set of functions:

```
fs = {Tanh[#] &, Tanh[# - 1] &, #/10 + 2/10 &, #/10 + 3/10 &}; 
Plot[Through[fs@x], {x, -5, 5}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we generate a set of points in each curve to work with the interpolations.

```
ListPlot@(pts =Transpose[Table[Thread[{x, Through[fs@x]}], {x, -5, 5, .1}]])
fInts = Interpolation /@ pts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next we calculate the limits for the integration:

```
pt1 = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{Line @@ {pts[[1]]}, Line @@ {pts[[3]]}}]
pt2 = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{Line @@ {pts[[2]]}, Line @@ {pts[[4]]}}]
Plot[Through[fInts@x], {x, -5, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Black, Point@pt1, Red, Point@pt2}, 
     Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally we perform the integration:

```
Plot[{Min[fInts[[1]]@x, fInts[[4]]@x], 
      Max[fInts[[2]]@x, fInts[[3]]@x]}, {x, pt1[[1, 1]], pt2[[1, 1]]}, 
      Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Black, Point@pt1, Red, Point@pt2}, 
      Evaluated -> True]
NIntegrate[
      Min[fInts[[1]]@x, fInts[[4]]@x] - 
      Max[fInts[[2]]@x, fInts[[3]]@x], {x, pt1[[1, 1]], pt2[[1, 1]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* 0.112747 *)
```

Compare with the exact value:

```
Integrate[
  Boole[fs[[1]]@x > fs[[4]]@x && 
        fs[[2]]@x < fs[[3]]@x] (Min[fs[[1]]@x, fs[[4]]@x] - 
                                Max[fs[[2]]@x, fs[[3]]@x]), {x, -5, 5}] // N 
(* 0.1  *)
```

Comment: this is really cool...learned a lot...thanks +1 of course :)

Comment: ps I particular like the numerical integration of relevant interpolating functions using Min and Max

Comment: @ubpdqn Glad you liked it. Thanks!